# Reference a specific item in a <string-array> from a preferences XML?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Assuming I have a string array defined as:

```
<string-array name="settings">
    <item>not very unique</item>
    <item>not very unique</item>
    <item>slightly more unique</item>
</string-array>
```

Is there a way to reference an item, by its index in the array, from a preferences XML?

I know how to reference the entire array:

```
android:entries="@array/settings"
```

But is there a way to reference only one item from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well no, there is no way, but you could do something like this:

```
<string name="mystring_1">awesome string is awesome</string>
<string name="mystring_2">even more awesome string</string>
<string-array name="mystrings">
    <item>@string/mystring_1</item>
    <item>@string/mystring_2</item>     
</string-array>
```

So you basically reference another string in your resources, that is referenced in your string array. ;)

Comment: Thanks! That's an excellent solution. I just managed to implement your proposed solution and it works!