# How Do I call String-array value in xml layout

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-layout

I have a string-array in my string.xml file in Android res/value folder like this

### my string.xml

```
<string-array name="books_titles_en">
    <item>Smoking Effeccts on Your Body</item>
    <item>Smoking - effects on your body</item>
    <item>How Tobacco Smoke Causes Disease</item>
    <item>patterns of use, health effects, use in smoking cessation and regulatory issues</item>
</string-array>
```

I need to retrieve the first element of array like this

### my home.xml

```
 <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/frag_1_text_pad"
                android:textSize="@dimen/frag_1_text_size"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/frg_1_text_right_pad"
                android:id="@+id/book_link0"
                android:text="@string-array/book_title_en[0]"/>
```

I know it seems like it will cause an error. How do I retrive these things on the string-array in string.xml in Android

Comment: It is not possible to do so normally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251595/reference-a-specific-item-in-a-string-array-from-a-preferences-xml see here

Comment: we can access string directly like android:text="@string/app_name"
so hope may be there is any ways available too.

Comment: @einschnaehkeee I have seen that earlier that get the thing from string to array. I ask for getting the thing from array to a compnent ( TextView ) in another my layout call home.xml

Comment: Its not have a direct way so need to thing how to get it directly ? Got Answer temporarily

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to giva a full answer to your problem:

There is no way of accessing an array directly, but you could do something like this:

```
<string name="books_titles_en_1">Smoking Effeccts on Your Body</string>
<string name="books_titles_en_2">Smoking - effects on your body</string>
<string name="books_titles_en_3">How Tobacco Smoke Causes Disease</string>
<string name="books_titles_en_4">patterns of use, health effects, use in smoking cessation and regulatory issues</string>
<string-array name="books_titles_en">
    <item>@string/books_titles_en_1</item>
    <item>@string/books_titles_en_2</item>
    <item>@string/books_titles_en_3</item>
    <item>@string/books_titles_en_4</item>
</string-array>
```

and then:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/frag_1_text_pad"
            android:textSize="@dimen/frag_1_text_size"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/frg_1_text_right_pad"
            android:id="@+id/book_link0"
            android:text="@string/book_title_en_1"/>
```

So you basically reference the neccessary strings directly, that are referenced in your string array. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link [Android - retrieve string array from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532907/android-retrieve-string-array-from-resources)

And this link [Help in getting String Array from arrays.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file)

Basically you will have to code for the array retrieval xml in the Java Class by making an adapter.

The first link I posted used

```
for(int i = 0; i < menuArray.length; i++) 
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(menuArray[i]);
        ll.addView(b);
    }
```

which is a sample of how to obtain the whole array from the xml.
You can modify it for single array value retrieval, or whichever array value you wish to retrieve.

Happy coding :D

Comment: No. I need to get the array value without using the java file. I need to access other xml file from the current xml file